# pygame.mouse.get_pressed() not working as I need in my button function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

As part of a game, I am attempting to create a login page in pygame. As I require buttons I have been trying to get a button function (that I saw on another tutorial page) to work. However, I seem to run into a problem with getting the program to register when the mouse is clicked. Below I have pasted my function for the button:

```
def button(self,msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))
    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = self.text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Each time I run my program - no matter what I do, my buttons remain static objects and do not change colour or allow any actions to run. Additionally the line 'print(click)' only ever outputs (0,0,0). I am using a laptop to code this program so maybe my trackpad is what is causing issues? I'm not too sure really but any alternatives on how to get this function to work would be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling this method? You would usually have separate logic for drawing a button and detecting if it was clicked, the latter usually in your event processing loop

Comment: @IainShelvington yes I call this in my main function using the following lines of code:         self.button("Login",225,175,125,50,blockCol,blockColAfter,self.login)
        self.button("Register",225,260,125,50,blockCol,blockColAfter,self.new_user)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

Comment: always put code, data and error messages in question, not in comment - it will be more readable

Comment: print mouse position and x+w, y+h or even `print(x+w > mouse[0] > x , y+h > mouse[1] > y)` to see if it gives True.

Comment: @Fazza usually you would have an event processing loop that would detect the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN/MOUSEBUTTONUP event. When this event is detected you would loop through all clickable objects and determine which was clicked and then perform some logic. At the moment you would only get the button that was pressed if it happened at the __exact__ time the method was being run

Answer (score 0):

With Pygame you usually run an event function in your main loop that handles all your events.

```
while self.playing:
    self.draw()
    self.events()
    etc...
```

In your event function you can write something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

        # Always here to make it possible to exit when pressing X in game window:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.playing = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # Left mouse button down events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if button.collidepoint(pos):
                        print('do what button is supposed to do')
```

Hope this helps!